# linking libcurl in Visual Studio 8

Tags: visual-studio, windows-7, libcurl

I have a C project needed to be compiled into a DLL.

This C project includes . I had compiled a libcurl.dll from source with VS2008.

I put the libcurl.dll in C:\Windows\System32 (I suppose this serves as installing the DLL)

Now, when I compile my own C project, it says 'cannot open include file curl/curl.h'.

Did I miss any steps? Sorry I'm really new to Windows system.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add the path to curl/curl.h as an additional include directory in your project settings.  Right click on the project, go to properties, and it's under the compiler section.

You'll also need to add curl.lib as a input library under your linker settings.

Comment: In Visual Studio 2010, there's also properties -> vc++ directories, which I believe is the preferred location.